# Problema con captura de coordenadas en canva

Tags: javascript, css, html5, canvas

Estoy teniendo unos problemas a la hora de hacer una pizarra con HTML, CSS y JS modificando un canvas. El problema es a la hora de capturar las coordenadas del ratón no sé porque pero no las captura bien. Pinta pero no en las coordenadas del ratón.

Los valores son introducidos a través de un configurador compuesto por varios inputs.
Cual es la cosa, la pizarra se crea sin ningún problema y la redimensión no es un problema, pero, pinta en coordenadas incorrectas, es como si pintase unas coordenadas x e y más abajo.

```js
"strict mode";
// ////////////////////SELECCIÓN-ELEMENTOS/////////////////////////
// *****INPUTS*****
let altoPiz = document.getElementById('alturaPiz');
let anchoPiz = document.getElementById('anchuraPiz');
let colorPiz = document.getElementById('colorPiz');
let patronPiz = document.getElementById('patronesPiz');
// *****ELEMENTOS*****
let pizarra = document.getElementById('pizarraCanva');
let resultadoParametros = document.getElementById('resultPiz');
let btnCrearPiz = document.getElementById('BtnCrearPiz');
let btnResetPiz = document.getElementById('BtnResetPiz');

// /////////////////////////VARIABLES//////////////////////////////
// Almacenamos el patrón seleccionado con anterioridad.
let patronActual = "noPatron";
// Almacenamos el contexto de la pizarra que usaremos.
let ctx;
// Almacenamos la posición del ratón.
let mousePos;
// Almacenamos el tamaño relativo a la ventana de la pizarra.
let TamanioPizarra;
// Almacenamos el alto de la pizarra:
let alto;
// Almacenamos el ancho de la pizarra.
let ancho;
// Boolean para permitir dibujar:
let dibujar = false;

// ////////////////////CREAR-RESET-PIZARRA/////////////////////////
btnCrearPiz.addEventListener("click", () => {
  try {
    // pasamos los valores introducidos en el input al canva.
    alto = altoPiz.value;
    ancho = anchoPiz.value;

    // Controlamos la excepción al introducir datos.
    if (alto <= 0 || ancho <= 0) {
      throw "Valor no valido, el tamaño debe ser mayor a 0px..."
    }
    pizarra.style.width = `${ancho}px`;
    pizarra.style.height = `${alto}px`;


    // Si no produce una excepción, saldrá un mensaje de confirmación.
    resultadoParametros.innerHTML = "Creada correctamente..."
    resultadoParametros.classList.remove('incorrecto');
    resultadoParametros.classList.add('correcto');

    // Guardamos el tamaño de la pizarra si esta esta preparada para utilizarse.
    if (pizarra && pizarra.getContext) {
      ctx = pizarra.getContext("2d");
      ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Si se produce una excepción, saldrá un mensaje informando del error.
    resultadoParametros.innerHTML = e;
    resultadoParametros.classList.add('incorrecto');
    resultadoParametros.classList.remove('correcto');
    // Reseteamos los valores de los inputs.
    altoPiz.value = 0;
    anchoPiz.value = 0;
  }
  //Limpiamos el mensaje de confirmación.
  setTimeout(() => {
    resultadoParametros.innerHTML = "";
  }, 2000)

})
// ////////////////////RESET-PIZARRA/////////////////////////
btnResetPiz.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // Reseteamos los valores de la altura y anchura de la pizarra.
  altoPiz.value = 0;
  anchoPiz.value = 0;
  pizarra.style.width = `0px`;

  pizarra.style.height = `0px`;
  // Mostramos un mensaje de confirmación.
  resultadoParametros.innerHTML = "Reseteada correctamente"
  resultadoParametros.classList.remove('incorrecto');
  resultadoParametros.classList.add('correcto');

  //Limpiamos el mensaje de confirmación.
  setTimeout(() => {
    resultadoParametros.innerHTML = "";
  }, 2000)
})

// ////////////////////DIBUJAR-EN-PIZARRA/////////////////////////
// 
pizarra.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
  dibujar = true;
  // LIMPIAR PIZARRA 
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ancho, alto);
  ctx.beginPath();

}, false);
// Agregamos un evento a la pizarra que detecte cuando se mueva el ratón por encima.
pizarra.addEventListener("mousemove", function(evt) {
  // Guardamos la pisición del ratón relativa.
  // mousePos={ //objeto
  //     x: evt.clientX,
  //     y: evt.clientY };
  if (dibujar) {
    ctx.lineTo(evt.clientX, evt.clientY);
    ctx.stroke();

  }
}, false);

//
pizarra.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
  dibujar = false;
}, false);

pizarra.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  dibujar = false;
}, false);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

#pizarraCanva {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: 0.5s;
}


/* El resto están en divs con posición fixed, no afectan. */
```

```html
<section id="pizarra">
  <div id="bancoTrabajo">
    <canvas id="pizarraCanva" class="noPatron"></canvas>
  </div>
  <button id="despliegueConf" class="girarDrch">A</button>
  <section id="configurador" class="deslizarIzq">
    <h4 class="encCuadro">Crear Pizarra</h4>
    <div class="verCuadroCnf">
      <label class="descInput">Introduzca el alto de la pizarra (px):</label>
      <input id="alturaPiz" class="inputsConfig" type="number" min="0" value="500">

      <label class="descInput">Introduzca el acho de la pizarra (px):</label>
      <input id="anchuraPiz" class="inputsConfig" type="number" min="0" value="500">

      <button id="BtnResetPiz">Reset</button>
      <button id="BtnCrearPiz">Añadir</button>
      <p id="resultPiz" class="correcto"></p>
    </div>
    <h4 class="encCuadro">Personalizar Pizarra </h4>
  </section>
```